# Find the corrupted doc in DynamoDB

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, database-migration, dynamoose

I am using dynamoose to scan a table. However one key (or more) seems to be corrupted. The scan fails with this error: **Expected _modifiedAt to be of type number, instead found type object**
The Schema is expecting a Number but somewhere in the table there is a doc where the key is an object.

How do I find this? We have thousands of keys, so I guess a simple search won't cut it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, since I need to do this because of a schema migration, I decided to simply [export all data as CSV](https://github.com/edasque/DynamoDBtoCSV) (This tool is only needed if you have over 100 keys, before that you can export directly within dynamoDB). And then write a custom migration script which handles all the error handling etc.

Hope this might help someone ;)